# Using Python and Python-Requests to simulate a user login to a .net form

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a simple form in my vb.net web application that is used by the user to login into the website.

I'm trying to simulate a user logging in using Python 3 and the Python Requests HTTP Library.

When I run the python script, I get a '200' for both the 'get' and 'post' status codes.

But when I print out the returned text after the post, it just prints out the HTML for the Login page.

I'm very new to Python, but I think it should work, but I'm probably missing something.

Here is my python code:

```
import requests

returnText = ''
r = requests.get('https://myappurl/Login.aspx')

returnCode = r.status_code
returnText = r.text

print('Get Status: ', returnCode)
# print('results: ', returnText)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'loginName':'admin','password':'abc123'}

session = requests.Session()
s = session.post('https://myappurl/Login.aspx',headers=headers,data=payload)

print('Post Status: ', s.status_code)
print('form cookies: ', session.cookies)
print('returned text: ', s.text)
```

Here is the vb.net code:

Login.aspx:

```
<form id="frmLogin" runat="server" defaultfocus="txtEmail">
  <div>
      <label for="txtEmail">Email:</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>

  <div>
      <label for="txtPassword">Password:</label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>

  <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['frmLogin'].submit();return false;" id="submit-btn">
        LOG IN
      </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the login link, this is called:

Login.aspx.vb:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   ' *** when user clicks the form "submit" button, this is loaded ***
   Call ValidateLogin()
End Sub

Here are the two relevant methods:

Sub ValidateLogin()
    ' *** get the values inside the textEmail and txtPassword TextBox controls
    Dim loginName As String = txtEmail.Text
    Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
    Dim loginMessage As String = String.Empty

    loginMessage = AuthUser(loginName, password)

    If loginMessage = "success" Then
       ' *** user is authenticated, load main web app screen ***
    End If

End Sub

Public Shared Function AuthUser(ByVal loginName As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    ' *** lots of code that checks "loginName" and "password" against a database call ***
    ' *** if both loginName and password are good then return "success"
    Return "Success"
End Function
```

I'm expecting to see the returned text(html) of the next page after successfully logging in, which is a list of games.

I've checked to make sure that the login and passwords are correct.  They work fine when I login normally to the website.

Is there anything I need to do or fix in my Python script so that it logs in successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the library BeautifulSoup to get all the hidden form fields fixed this for me.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {} URL="https://myappurl/Login.aspx" 
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"}

username = "me@me.me" 
password = "mypassword123"

s = requests.Session() 
s.headers.update(headers) 
r=s.get(URL) 

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value'] 
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value'] 
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE, 
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, 
"__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION, 
"frmControlNameForLoginNameField":username, 
"frmControlNameForPasswordField":password, 
"submit-btn":"frmLogin"}

r=s.post(URL, data=login_data) 
print (r.url) 
print (r.content)
```